# Detect timezone before all data load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have event pages show date and time. For logged in member, I can just grab their preferred timezone.  But for those user not sign in, I want to detect their laptop timezone first, and display the page in their local timezone. 
I use jquery in application.html.erb:

```
<% if session[:time_zone].blank? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.ajax({
            data: {user_time_zone: $().get_timezone()},
            type: 'post',
            url: "/set_time_zone_session"
        })
    </script>
```

**Question:** It runs jQuery last, so at first time, the page shows the default timezone. after refresh the page, all the sub-sequence requests timezone get set properly. 
Besides, reload the page after first request with javascript, is there a better way to do this?

**Extra**: If I have to reload the page. I add location.reload(); after jQuery call. The reload happens after first request complete. Is there a way to reload the page right away, before the first request get loaded? Otherwise, it will be so weird that page get loaded twice.

Comment: Have a look at the javascript function, getTimezoneOffset : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting a cookie with the timezone on the client 
and then simply reloading the page.  that will keep your rails app simple.

(p.s. A HTTP request might contain a "Date" header giving the clients date + time. You can use that when producing your rubyonrails output, no need for ajax at all.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18
But the more common case would be that the client does not send a date header.)